# Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::productDetail() must be an instance of App\Product, string given

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route

```
Route::get('catalog/{category}/{product}', 'HomeController@productDetail')->name('product.index2');
```

And controller

```
public function productDetail(categories $categories, product $product)
{
    $products = product::where('active', 1)->get();

    if($product->categories != $categories){
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('products', compact('product', 'products'));
}
```

##### The error

> Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::productDetail() must be an instance of App\Product, string given

##### Front

```
<ul class="accordion-menu">
    @foreach ($categories as $item)
        <li>
            <div class="dropdownlink">{{$item->name}} <img src="{{ asset('build/img/d1.svg') }}" alt="Банковские терминалы"></div>
            <ul class="submenuItems">
                @foreach($item->children as $subcategory)
                    <li><a href="{{route('category.index2', $subcategory)}}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
                
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach                    
</ul>
```

##### `kernel.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you called this route ?

Comment: You are using Model Bindings. Could you show us your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file just to make sure you have the correct middlewares set up?

Comment: Please share the link **<a></a>** that you use to call the `product.index2` route. you shared the one that calls the route `category.index2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your route and your controller method expect 2 parameter one is category object and the other is product object. But when you call route give only one parameter.

```
Route::get('catalog/{category}/{product}', 'HomeController@productDetail')->name('product.index2');
```

you need to pass your product object also like below,

```
<li><a href="{{route('category.index2', ['category'=> $subcategory, 'product'=>$product ])}}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>
```

Comment: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::productDetail() must be an instance of App\Product, string given

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

Your function like this

```
public function productDetail(categories $categories, product $product)
{
    $products = Product::where('active', 1)->get();
    if($product->categories != $categories){
        abort(404);
    }
    return view('products', compact('product', 'products'));
}
```

Your view like this

```
<ul class="accordion-menu">
    @foreach ($categories as $item)
        <li>
            <div class="dropdownlink">{{$item->name}} <img src="{{ asset('build/img/d1.svg') }}" alt="Банковские терминалы"></div>
            <ul class="submenuItems">
                @foreach($item->children as $subcategory)
                    <li><a href="{{route('category.index2', [$subcategory,$product)}}">{{ $subcategory->name }}</a></li>// please add second parameter for product
                @endforeach

            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach                    
</ul>
```

**Note**: May be you call wrong route because your route name is `product.index2` not `category.index2`